# How to ensure GStreamer has grabbed frames before decoding a jpeg

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-18.04

I have a GStreamer pipeline that grabs an mjpeg webcam stream from 3 separate cameras, and saves 2 frames each. I'm executing these commands on the USB 3.0 bus of an Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu 18.04  When doing this, I discovered I would occasionally get a garbled image like this in the collection of output images:

[image: garbage image]

It wouldn't always happen, but maybe 1/5 executions an image might look like that.

I then discovered if I decode the jpeg then re-encode, this doesn't ever happen. See the below pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=2 ! \
image/jpeg,width=3840,height=2160 ! queue ! jpegdec ! queue ! \
jpegenc ! multifilesink location=/root/cam0_%02d.jpg v4l2src \ 
device=/dev/video1 num-buffers=2 ! image/jpeg,width=3840,height=2160 ! \
queue ! jpegdec ! queue ! jpegenc ! multifilesink  \
location=/root/cam1_%02d.jpg v4l2src device=/dev/video2 num-buffers=2 !  \ 
image/jpeg,width=3840,height=2160 ! queue ! jpegdec ! queue ! jpegenc ! \
multifilesink location=/root/cam2_%02d.jpg
```

Now, when I run this pipeline I have a 1/5 chance of getting this error:

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstJpegDec:jpegdec0: No valid frames decoded before end of stream
```

Is there a way to make gstreamer wait for the frames instead of simply failing? I attempted this by adding the !queue! in the above pipeline, to no success.

Comment: Are you looking for `jpegparse`?

Comment: Hi again Florian, I tried putting jpegparse in replacement of the decode/encode, and BEFORE the decode/encode. Same results!

Comment: Hmm too bad. I thought it would collect data chunks to complete frames in case your cam would not deliver them in a single buffer.

Comment: How are you watching the saved image data? With jpegdec too? Or something else? I mean - if you get incomplete frames from the cam due to bandwidth constraints it may be that the jpegdec drops the frame completely. If that happens for both samples the jpegenc will never get any data and you will get the EOS before sample error message.

Comment: Perhaps try `avdec_mjpeg`. I think that one can output corrupt data. It will probably look corrupt after jpegenc though. If you get bad data in the first place it is hard to recover..

Comment: Will do - I'll report back on this tomorrow, I just took my camera rig down to change some mechanical aspects.

Comment: Hi Florian - Wow, so avdec_mjpeg seems to have a built in handler for overrunning the bus. With this command, I occasionally, get an image fragment (not mixed-up like above, but maybe 3/4 of the image with green remaining), but I ALWAYS get images, and 99% of the time they're good. I see GST is outputting the following to the CLI: Redistribute latency...
Thanks for your help!